# PowerShell GUI csv import to ListView

Tags: powershell

I have a script to rename computers on my domain. Now i am trying to create my first GUI and incorporate that script. I created a GUI using visual studio WPF project. The goal is to have the option to manually enter computers and their new name via two text box or to be able to import a csv file. Both of those options should populate the Listview. then click run and it will rename all computers in the listview. I am looking for help on the import button function right now. If there is a different way i should be doing this I am definitely open to suggestions.

Current Code

```
#LoadForm

./LoadDialog.ps1 -XamlPath 'C:\Forms\ReNamer.xaml'

#EVENT Handler

$oldname = $CurrentNameBox
$newName = $NewNameBox
##$renameBtn.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
$csvPath = $csvBox
$csvBtn.Add_Click({GetCompList})

#Launch the window

$xamGUI.ShowDialog() | out-null


    #Csv import button
   Function GetCompList{
   Write-Host "Importing Computers from CSV file"
   $csvfile = "C:\Sysinternals\rename.csv"
   Import-Csv $csvfile | foreach { 
   $oldName = $_.OldName;
   $newName = $_.NewName;
    }
   }

   Function RenameComputers{
   Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $o to: $n"
   netdom renamecomputer $o /newName:$n /uD:sdirc\clarkj8 /passwordD:$p /force /reboot
    }
```

ListView xaml

```
 <ListView Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="194" Margin="10,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Old Computer Name" Width="175"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="New Computer Name" Width="175"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

GUI
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead use a datagrid and use code similar to this:

```
$csv = import-csv C:\csv.csv | Select-Object @{Name=‘OldName‘;Expression={$_.OldName}},`
                                             @{Name=‘NewName’;Expression={$_.NewName}}

$csv | % { $datagrid.AddChild($_) }
```

I used code similar to this in a PowerShell GUI project I used. Csv would have to have headers like OldName,NewName.

EDIT: And your header names in the datagrid have to be the same as in $csv

Comment: OK i got that to work kinda. when i click the import button it now loads the correct amount of rows. but they are empty and as far as i can tell it is not displaying a second column. Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to add bindings to the columns in the xaml.  <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding 'OldName'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Name" Width="0.25*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding 'NewName'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Job Title" Width="0.25*"/>                 For some reason I'm unable to format this message, but check the columns are the same name as in $csv. The bindings should be the only other thing you need.